# Apply a patch file in Windows using Mingw

Tags: mingw, patch

How can I apply a patch file for a source directory in Windows using Mingw?

Answer (score 6):

Get msys-patch using mingw-get

```
mingw-get install msys-patch
```

Then just use patch like unix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)