# bazel server terminated abruptly (error code :14, error message: '',log file: 'c:\users\lee\_bazel_lee\zjiu63sl/server/jvm.out

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-lite

Hi I used bazel in Windows 7

I try bazel build tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco in cmd.exe

Then I got error message : server terminated abruptly (error code :14, error message: '',log file: 'c:\users\lee_bazel_lee\zjiu63sl/server/jvm.out

What can I do? Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeq1L.png)

Try in tensorflow-master folder, I got error message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkJS5.png)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build from *outside* of the tensorflow directory. You need to run Bazel from within `tensorflow-master` to build the target `//tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco:toco`. Do you mind trying that out?

Comment: I try it but I got error message :- no such package '@eigen_archive//' ~

Comment: I did edit my question. Please note image 2nd description.

Comment: Dupe of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41480#issuecomment-1060272920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current error message states that the command "patch" is not found. I gues your mingw installation has not installed this programm. See [Apply a patch file in Windows using Mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639036/apply-a-patch-file-in-windows-using-mingw) how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient memory space will lead to this error. Use `-- local_ ram_ Resources = 40960` to limit the memory size.